# Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init

Tags: boot, init

I installed 10.10 a few days ago. The **only** changes to the default install are the addition of Chrome and Pinta.

It was fine for a few days, then today login etc seemed slow. Likewise it couldn't even render the restart/shutdown menus.

Hoping it was some botched update, I ran the update manager; it tried to install but failed (the UI didn't make it obvious *what* had failed).

Fine, ok. Shut it down (press enter on the blank shut-down dialog).

Fire it up hoping... And... #fail.

```
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
```

Is it now a brick?

---

More details:

```
GRUB 1.98+20100804-5ubuntu3
```

With

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-22-generic
```

Causes

```
udevadm trigger is not permitted while udev is unxonfigured
Giving up waiting for root device.
```

Or

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-23-generic
```

Causes

```
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
```

Then the same for /sys and /process

Comment: `/sbin/init` is the first thing the kernel looks for on the root filesystem. This message in fact shows (99.999% of the time) that the root filesystem couldn't be mounted (or maybe that the wrong filesystem was mounted). What are the previous few messages? If you don't see many messages, press the `Shift` key as soon as the BIOS has initialized the keyboard and hold it until you see the Grub menu. On the `linux` line, remove `quiet splash`, then try booting.

Comment: @Gilles I think it was failure to mount; I will need to swap disks again to capture it...

Comment: Oh, if you have multiple disks, describe your disk layout precisely. Did you move disks around between the installation and your latest attempts? Is there any possibility of flaky hardware (loose cable, bad RAM, etc.)? What's on the `linux` line in Grub (if it's a UUID, not need to copy it out)?

Comment: @Gilles the disk setup is simpler than you think... One is in the machine, and the other is in an anti-static bag on my desk :) two seconds, I'll swap it and get the info.

Comment: @Gilles is that enough?

Comment: The relevant messages would be a little earlier. Look for something like “unable to mount root fs”, and a few lines before. It may be more productive to boot from a live CD/USB and: check if you can access the disk, look in `/var/log/kern.log` there for filesystem or disk errors (search especially for `sda`).

Comment: @Gilles they kinda scrolled off too quickly ;p I'll dig out my USB stick...

Comment: On a Linux console, `Shift+PgUp` scrolls up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suggested fix can be found here:  http://pinoy-computing-tips.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-fix-ubuntu-error-no-init-found.html

Quoting:

> This morning, a friend came to me with
>   his laptop that won't boot. At every
>   boot attempt, his Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid
>   Lynx system outputs the following
>   error messages:
>
> ```
> mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/***************************** on /root
> failed: Invalid argument
> mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
> mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
> mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
> mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
>
> Target file system doesn't have /sbin/init
> No init found. Try passing init= bootarg
>
> Busybox v1.13.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu7) built-in shell (ash)
> Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
> (initramfs) _
> ```
>
> Booting into "Recovery Mode" as well
>   as choosing the other kernels listed
>   in grub didn't help at all.
>
> Solution:
>
> 1. Boot from the Ubuntu Live CD;
> 2. Open/Run Terminal;
> 3. Type: `sudo fdisk -l` (to get the device name) then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>;
>
>    ```
>    Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes 
>    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders
>    Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
>    Disk identifier: **********
>
>    Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
>    /dev/sda1 * 1 30238 242886703+ 83 Linux
>    /dev/sda2 30239 30401 1309297+ 5 Extended
>    /dev/sda5 30239 30401 1309266 82 Linux swap / Solaris
>    ```
>
>    The device name for my friend's system
>      based on the above: `/dev/sda1`
> 4. Type: `sudo fsck /dev/sda1` then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>;
> 5. Restart the system and boot normally.

Comment: As an addendum to this, you may need to force `fsck` to check again by using the `f` option. Eg: `fsck -f /dev/sda1`.

Comment: Excellent! I was worried it wouldn't work as my Ubuntu Live DVD was a 2-years older version.

Comment: I am getting the error the fdisk will not work becuase of GPT partition. How to proceed?

Comment: Thanks. It worked for ubuntu 14.04 as well.

Comment: it worked, just need to make sure we enter the correct device name on step 4. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem when I upgrade my existing Ubuntu 12.04 Precise to Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty. During the installation completed it suddenly hang-up around 5~10mins so I force to shutdown my laptop. I tried to boot it again and this error display:

```
...
...
Target file system doesn't have /sbin/init
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg

Busybox v1.13.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu7) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
(initramfs) _
```

I solved it by following this instruction
[Ubuntu 14.04 doesn' t boot after upgrade from 12.04 installed inside Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452631/ubuntu-14-04-doesn-t-boot-after-upgrade-from-12-04-installed-inside-windows-8-1).
And it magically works from my end.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the file didn't exist after an upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. I fixed it executing:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
chroot /mnt
apt-get install init
update-initramfs -u
reboot
```