# Upgraded to 14.04 reboot fail

Tags: boot, upgrade, 14.04

I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04, and when I restarted the computer and selected Ubuntu, the black screen said:

```
mount: mounting/dev/loop0 on/root failed: Invalid Argument
mount: mounting/dev on/root/dev failed: No Such File or Directory
mount: mounting/sys on/root/sys failed: No Such File or Directory
mount: mounting/proc on/root/proc failed: No Such File or Directory
Target Filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init=bootarg.
BusyBox v.1.21.1 (Ubuntu1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1)built-in shell(ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)_
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: This solved the problem, I see the desktop but it keeps loading without entering Ubuntu environment

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem this morning, after my 13.10 to 14.04 upgrade last night. My setup is a dual boot with Windows, using the windows boot manager.

I found the solution here: [same issue with Win 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452631/ubuntu-14-04-doesn-t-boot-after-upgrade-from-12-04-installed-inside-windows-8-1)

The precis is:

1. When I select Ubuntu from the boot manager, I hold the shift key
2. This brings up Grub manager
3. With the first line selected, hit "e"
   (for edit)
4. Hunt down through the boot instructions to a long command line that includes options "ro quiet splash"
5. Change the "ro" to "rw" (readonly to read-write)
6. ctl-x to save and run

This brought me right up in 14.04 LTS. The disclaimer is that I don't have any idea why it worked. I then edited /boot/grub.cfg to make this same change permanent (suggestions on the correct way to do this appreciated).

Comment: well dang, I have no idea how you figured that out, but it works! I was on wubi if that makes any difference...