# Problem with installing ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS Trusty Tahr

Tags: boot, mount

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS was installed, functioning well. I just installed the new Trusty Tahr version. Restarting the laptop the message below appeared. How to solve?

```
mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on root/failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target file system doesn't have requested /sbin/init
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for list of build-in commands
(initramfs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[Ubuntu 14.04 doesn' t boot after upgrade from 12.04 installed inside Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452631/ubuntu-14-04-doesn-t-boot-after-upgrade-from-12-04-installed-inside-windows-8-1?rq=1)

It worked for me on a dual boot machine with W7. I had to edit 9 or 10 lines and my linux is back