# Failure to upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade

I was trying to upgrade to 14.04, everything vent fine without errors but after reboot the system has crashed. I am getting this error message:

```
mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on /root failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(inittramfs) _
```

I was running linux on a dual boot Asus UX31E machine. W7 is still booting normal.

Comment: **Definite duplicate** of [Ubuntu 14.04 doesn' t boot after upgrade from 12.04 installed inside Windows 8.1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452631/ubuntu-14-04-doesn-t-boot-after-upgrade-from-12-04-installed-inside-windows-8-1)