# upgrading to ubuntu 14.04, edit grub.cfg ro to rw everywhere?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade

I was upgrading my ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 and was having this exact [Ubuntu 14.04 doesn' t boot after upgrade from 12.04 installed inside Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452631/ubuntu-14-04-doesn-t-boot-after-upgrade-from-12-04-installed-inside-windows-8-1) problem.

I have been able to start my system but I want clarify that should I change all the occurrences of 'ro quite splash' to 'rw quite splash' in grub.cfg? There are two places that 'ro quite splash' occurs in grub.cfg file. I am very new with ubuntu. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - in the terminal type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/10_lupin
```

This opens the text editor. Then find the line that looks like

```
linux ${rel_dirname}/${basename} root=${LINUX_HOST_DEVICE} loop=${loop_file_relative} ro ${args}
```

and replace ro with rw, then save (you need sudo for the save part)

then you need to rebuild your grub file so (again in the terminal) type

```
sudo update-grub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If gedit is not installed, every other editor should work like e.g. geany, vim, emacs, ....