# Ubuntu 14.04 seems to have failed to upgrade from 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade

I recently attempted to update to Ubuntu 14.04 from Ubuntu 12.04. Everything seemed to work without error until it restarted. When the computer fired back up, I was greeted with the following message in what was basically a full-screen terminal (which I copied by hand):

```
mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on /root failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.


BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

The `_` at the end is a prompt, and typing `help` as suggested gives me a list of some basic commands like `ls` and `cd`.

What's going on here? Is this recoverable, or should I scrap everything and do a fresh install? In case it matters, I installed Ubuntu about a year ago as a dual boot with Windows 7 via the wubi installer. I also just read that wubi is being discontinued as of 13.04, so perhaps this was part of the problem.

**EDIT** I've found a possible solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452631/ubuntu-14-04-doesn-t-boot-after-upgrade-from-12-04-installed-inside-windows-8-1), I'm going to give it a shot. In the meantime, other suggestions as backup if this doesn't work are welcome.

Comment: Could you boot in recovery and dump the contents of your `/etc/fstab` file?

Comment: I found someone else with the same message when they tried to boot after upgrading [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452631/ubuntu-14-04-doesn-t-boot-after-upgrade-from-12-04-installed-inside-windows-8-1), so I'm trying that first.

Comment: Fixing a faild upgrade almost takes longer and is less reliable then just performing a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but if you used Wubi, I think your Ubuntu might have been running as a Windows program. Do you remember how you installed Ubuntu the first time? There are some simple commands to fix the Windows boot if you have a Windows recovery disk. Here is [the Microsoft page that explains bootrec](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392).

I have used it before and it worked quite well. If you get Windows running again, you might want to use system restore if you have a recently saved restore point. I don't know if you can upgrade an installation of Ubuntu that runs under Windows. I would remove Ubuntu from Windows using Windows' **install/remove programs** and then do a fresh dual boot installation or use the later version of Ubuntu to do a new side by side installation if you can save all your documents before you delete Ubuntu.

Comment: After attempting the upgrade, Windows was actually unaffected (that's where I posted the original question), and it thinks I have Ubuntu 12.04.4-rev280 when I look at the installed programs. I just tried the solution given in the question that I linked to earlier, and it seems to have worked, though I do have a message that pops up saying there's an internal Ubuntu error. Would you recommend that I continue with your suggestion and do a fresh install, or do you think the solution I found will work?

Comment: Further update: the "internal error" message has stopped appearing after booting a second time. Everything seems to be working, and it appears that you can upgrade Ubuntu when it's running under Windows, but it's a bit more complicated and Windows doesn't know you've actually upgraded it.

Comment: Glad to see it is working now! I personally feel better about having Ubuntu on a separate partition. It has helped me to recover files from Windows many times when Windows crashed. But it is a good idea to check the Ubuntu compatibility list for 14.04 if you have an older computer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452631/ubuntu-14-04-doesn-t-boot-after-upgrade-from-12-04-installed-inside-windows-8-1?lq=1) that didn't want to show up as a possible duplicate when I was writing my question. Note that I *cannot guarantee that this is a safe solution*, but it should work if you've installed Ubuntu as a dual boot with Windows and have the same message as I had above when you try to boot. I've summarized the answer at the link here:

- When you turn on your computer, select to boot Ubuntu, and hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to run Grub, the boot loader for Ubuntu.
- Press <kbd>E</kbd> to display the commands that Grub uses to boot Ubuntu.
- Look through these commands to find where it says `ro quiet splash` and change this to `rw quiet splash`.
- Press the boot key (it says what you can use at the bottom of the screen; my options were <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).
- Now Ubuntu should boot properly, but the settings that we changed haven't stuck yet. You'll need to run `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` (or you can use whatever text editor you prefer) to change the default boot settings.
- Find the line which reads `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and add `rw` to the parameter so that it's the same as what we used to boot.
- Save the file and exit the editor.
- Run `sudo update-grub` to generate a new grub config file.

Now, if you reboot Ubuntu, you should find that it works as expected.