# target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init. /bin/sh: 0 : Can't open splash - Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: boot

I have an Ubuntu 15.04 machine. I installed docker in this machine. After installation I was trying to run the test image of docker which comes by default. But it did not ran. Then I tried to shutdown the machine.

But the machine was not shutting down. It just hanged in the middle and was consuming all of the cpu resources. I waited for 10-15 mins but state did not change and nothing happened. So I went ahead and shutdown the machine by pressing the power-on button in laptop for a while. This way the machine went off.

After this event, now when I am trying to boot into the machine, it is throwing me following error at the time of boot.

```
Target filesystem doesn't hvae requested /sbin/init.
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash
[4.458446] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00
[4.458479] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: sh not tainted 3.13.0-46-generic #79-Ubuntu
```

Machine has three os: Windows, Centos, Ubuntu-15.04.

I have tried the `fsck` solution on the boot device with network boot. But it does not solve this problem.

Here I don't know if docker package is part of the problem. It could have been any package installation for that matter.

The output of fsck is as follows:

```
$ fsck /dev/sda5
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
/dev/sda5: clean, 885843/1313280 files, 3569836/5242880 blocks.
```

I have also tried `-f` option of `fsck`, output for that is:

```
 
$ fsck /dev/sda5 -f
fsck /dev/sda5 -f
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda5: 885843/1313280 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 3569836/5242880 blocks
```

Running `fdisk -l` command prints following message, along with printing device details.

```
Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I mounted the device using `mount -o ro /dev/sda5 /media/boot` command.
And the output of `ls -l /media/boot` is as follows:

```
total 116
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 26 07:01 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Dec 26 07:10 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan  4  2015 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Apr 17  2014 dev
drwxr-xr-x 164 root root 12288 Jan 26 07:04 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan  4  2015 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Feb 27  2015 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Feb  4  2015 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root  4096 Jan 26 07:01 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec 26 06:49 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec 26 06:28 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Jan  4  2015 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jan  4  2015 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 10  2014 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Oct  2 14:15 opt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 10  2014 proc
drwx------  11 root root  4096 Jan 26 10:30 root
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Apr 17  2014 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Jan 26 07:03 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 17  2014 srv
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 13  2014 sys
drwxrwxrwt   6 root root  4096 Jan 26 22:01 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Oct  2 14:14 usr
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4096 Jan  9 02:05 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Feb 27  2015 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Feb  4  2015 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try this [solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17647/target-filesystem-doesnt-have-requested-sbin-init)

Comment: Already tried this solution but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `/sbin/init` file is corrupted as you were trying to force shutdown.

One thing you can do is:

1. Make a boot-able USB with the same 15.04 by using unetbootIn or Startup disk creator
2. Connect it in your PC boot into that USB
3. Select the option try Ubuntu without installing
4. Here search for the partition where your 15.04 installed, it might be `/dev/sda1` to `n`. There we need to replace `/sbin` completely with our installation source's `/sbin`.

You can use `sudo mv` command for that, after replacing /sbin, reboot   your system.

It will work :)

Comment: I tried this for 16.04 and it didn't work (same error). What else can you do at this point?

Answer (score 0):

I used **unetbootin** to fix this problem, now it's running like a rockstar.
I just made a bootable USB, logged in as default, removed the default filesystem's `/sbin` to my  Main `/sbin`.

Please do it via root. 
As simple as that. 
Voila! It's Running.