# Target file system doesn't have requested /sbin/init

Tags: 14.04, boot

Yesterday I removed a Docker package with: `sudo apt-get --purge`, and today when I started my PC I found this problem.

```
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init/. 
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash 
[ 5.475504] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00 
[ 5.475504] 
[ 5.475552] CPU: 0 PID: Comm: sh Not tainted 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu
```

[image]

Comment: Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init/.                                            /bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash                                                                            [   5.475504] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attemptes to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00                                                                                         [   5.475504]                                                                                              [   5.475552] CPU: 0 PID: Comm: sh Not tainted 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to fix it? If so, you could share your solution here.

I too had this problem a few days back. And while I found various suggestions across forums that worked for someone else, it didn't work for me.

Finally I came across this solution here, that led me in the right direction

[target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init. /bin/sh: 0 : Can't open splash - Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727810/target-filesystem-doesnt-have-requested-sbin-init-bin-sh-0-cant-open-spl?noredirect=1&lq=1)

To summarize,

1. Create a fresh Ubuntu startup disk
2. Boot into it live (Select "Try Ubuntu")
3. Get the path of the /sbin folder of your installed OS (it will be /media/ubuntu/"something here"/sbin)
4. Copy the /sbin folder of your live ubuntu into your installed OS
   (sudo cp -a /sbin/. /media/ubuntu/"something here"/sbin/)
5. Restart PC, and you should boot into your regular installed OS