# Kernel Panic - not syncing - Attempted to kill init ! exit code 0x00007f00

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, windows-8

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS dual boot with windows 8. Yesterday I was installing hadoop on my system and suddenly Ubuntu stopped working. So I have to power it off directly by pressing and holding power button. After that when I restarted Ubuntu i got this error.

[image: Kernel Panic]

I have googled a lot and after that i was able to remove this error for a moment and getting a new error:

> Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init

I have tried this solution given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17647/target-filesystem-doesnt-have-requested-sbin-init)

And I was able to boot into system but unable to login so when I restarted my system again i started getting the `kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode = 0x00007f00`

I need to boot into system as many of my projects are under progress So reinstalling Ubuntu is not a option for me.

Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: I've same issue while I dist upgrade from 14.04, I'm even not able to boot with old kernel and rescue more, how did you solve it. ????

Comment: i found no solution so i reinstalled the OS.

Comment: I've installed new kernel and regenerated init image and now server up

Comment: how to install new kernel ? I am facing the same issue .

Answer (score 1):

I was able to access the data by using a ubuntu disc and using the try ubuntu options. (hopes this help people who are trying to access their data)