# Can't boot into ubuntu server; target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init

Tags: boot, server, mount

I haven't used my ubuntu server for a few weeks now but I haven't done anything with it since I last successfully used it. I use it as mostly a media server.

After trying to access it from my windows computer, I wasn't able to. I assumed it just needed to be rebooted so that's what I did. Turns out there's a different issue. When I booted up, I got this message:

```
Target filesystem doesn't have reuqested /sbin/init.
/bin/sh: 0: can't access tty; job control turned off
```

I followed the steps in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17647/target-filesystem-doesnt-have-requested-sbin-init) post (using fsck) but nothing changed. Every previous version of Ubuntu I tried to run gave me the same error.

I was able to access the filesystems (there are two) by booting into a Fedora CD . The first one was the hard drive with the majority of my files. The other one was ubuntu server.

It seems as though the system is having trouble mounting the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

The error may be because of the user with which you are trying to login to the server.

The user may be having no login shell configured.