# Not able to boot Ubuntu desktop

Tags: boot, init

I have been using Ubuntu Desktop for a while now, but today for some reason I am not able to start it. Here is what I see.

[image]

I have tried rebooting and starting it in recovery mode. but seems to be of no help. I am downloading fresh copy of Ubuntu so that I can play around with steps mentioned here - [Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17647/target-filesystem-doesnt-have-requested-sbin-init)

> ***Here is what I have tried.***
>
> I booted Ubuntu from USB
>
> Saw 4 options : 
>   1. Try Ubuntu without installing 
>   2. Install Ubuntu 
>   3. OEM Install 
>   4. Check disc for defects
>
> I went to first option. Opened terminal --> `sudo fdisk -l`
>
> This gave me my actual device name --> `/dev/sda1`
>
> Then I executed --> `sudo fsck /dev/sda1`
>
> Rebooted again from Hard disk. Same issue persist. Anything I am
>   missing?

Will keep this thread updated. Meanwhile, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: And what did you tried ?

Comment: Hey @lkj - I tried rebooting and starting it in recovery mode. but seems to be of no help. I am downloading fresh copy of Ubuntu so that I can play around with steps mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17647/target-filesystem-doesnt-have-requested-sbin-init), as pointed out by karel

You have any better suggestions?

Comment: we can not help if you not describe in details what you tried. step by step. otherwise we can not give you a step by step description of helping steps. troubleshooting is always painful from distance. sorry.

Comment: No worries @lkj , I have updated the thread with what I have already tried and what i am trying. Will keep the thread updated :) Good luck.

Comment: I tried doing this. Booted from Ubuntu USB

I saw 4 options

1. Try Ubuntu without installing
2. Install Ubuntu
3. OEM Install
4. Check disc for defects....

the question is how do I open terminal to run fsck