# /sbin/init : no such file or directory | Not able to boot ubuntu desktop

Tags: boot, boot-repair, init, initrd

I have been using Ubuntu Desktop for a while now, but today for some reason I am not able to start it. Here is what I see.

[image]

Here is what I have already tried :

1. Tried booting in recovery mode
2. Executed fsck from bootable USB.

Here is what I did after booting from USB:

1. Created a bootable USB
2. Saw 4 options:

   - Try Ubuntu without installing
   - Install Ubuntu
   - OEM Install
   - Check disc for defects

I went to first option. Opened terminal --> `sudo fdisk -l`

This gave me my actual device name --> `/dev/sda1`

Then I executed --> `sudo fsck /dev/sda1` as mentioned here - [Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17647/target-filesystem-doesnt-have-requested-sbin-init)

Here is the output:

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda1: clean, 682451/29483008 files, 26039796/117925888 blocks
```

Tried rebooting and booting from HDD but same issue

3. Booted again from USB and selected try Ubuntu without installing. Executed - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`

This is what the output looks like - https://pastebin.com/Yi4PqRU4

Also tried option 4 `check disk defects`. Result was `No defects found`

Help?

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the initrd is corrupted or missing. In that case it would be unable to find the init process that the initrd needs and uses. Follow these steps to rebuild the initrd:

1. Boot from the Media (USB/DVD) and start your terminal session as root. ("Rescue Mode")
2. Mount the disk with the root filesystem to /mnt

`mount /path/to/disk /mnt`

3. Mount and bind the virtual filesystems onto your disk

`mount --rbind /proc /mnt/proc
 mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys
 mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev`

4. chroot into your disk

`chroot /mnt`

5. Mount everything else, if any

`mount -a`

6. move into the boot directory

`cd /boot`

7. rebuild the initrd

In RedHat it's as simple as running this command:

`mkinitrd`

In Ubuntu it looks like they use a different tool. First, you'll need to see what kernel version you are using:

```
# ls /lib/modules/
3.11.0-12-generic
```

Then use the version it gives you to run the necessary command:

```
# update-initramfs -c -k 3.11.0-12-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
```

After that you can `exit` chroot and try booting normally again to see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Hey @TopHat, what do you mean by rescue mode?

Comment: @FaisalMemon Sorry for the confusion, I come from a RedHat/SUSE background where they use the terminology of "rescue mode". Basically, it just means to live boot from the USB or DVD media.

Comment: Hey @TopHat, I tried this, but same issue persist. Here what I exectued after I selected "Try Ubuntu without installing" - https://pastebin.com/mRQKQUqg

Comment: @FaisalMemon you may wanna try the same steps with kernel "4.4.0-59-generic" instead since it is the later kernel. Other than that the only other idea I have right now is to try all the same steps I recommend as before except for step 7 try re-installing grub instead of rebuilding the initrd with the `grub-install` command in the /boot directory.

Comment: I tried same on 4.4.0-59-generic also, but same issue persist.

Comment: @FaisalMemon ah, that's unfortunate. Well, the only other idea I had/have is for you to try that `grub-install` I mentioned in my previous comment. Hopefully that does the trick.

Comment: sure. let me try and get back to you.

Comment: Tried running `grub-install`. Message I get is `Installing for i386-pc platform. grub-install: error: install device isnt specified`

Comment: Do I need to run it like `grub-install /dev/sda1` where `/dev/sda1` is the device?

Comment: @FaisalMemon sorry for the confusion. I was thinking it would assume the disk/partition of the directory you are in. If you have a separate `/boot/` partition then choose that partition, otherwise, the root partition. Your example should be right syntax-wise.

Comment: Check this - https://pastebin.com/ig1X0wV1
Seeing this now :(

Comment: @FaisalMemon Dang. :( For kicks and giggles, try running the command on the device as a whole instead of the specific partition: `grub-install /dev/sda` After that though, I'm out of ideas. Sorry. :(

Comment: Haha. Finished. No error reported :) Rebooting now to see if issue is solved :)

Comment: And the issue persist :P

Comment: @FaisalMemon **facepalm**  well hopefully someone else responds with more wisdom than me. If you're able to increase your reputation enough you can put a bounty on the question. Let me know if you ever figure it out!

Comment: Sure. since this thing is taking too long. I think I should go ahead and reinstall ubuntu. Can try this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder

What do you think?

Comment: @FaisalMemon I'd say make sure you have a backup of important data, then give it a go!