# How do I check if last shutdown was clean for Ubuntu 20.04? Each boot runs ckfs

Tags: boot, shutdown, fsck

I researched this and the answer is for 2011 system versions. Can you update the Kernel or Systemd print logs? Each boot runs ckfs.  I did HDD tests to find out about it health.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/970437/15811 change sda2 to your device.

Comment: The divice patitions are clean. I would like logs Kernel and systemd of clean shutdown for Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04.