# Kernel tainted and attempted to kill init ubuntu 16.04.06

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel, live-usb

[image: This is the image of what loads on my screen when I try I try to boot up ubuntu. I don't know how to fix this error. The Kernel is tainted, and I'm not able to fix anything at the moment because accessing any mode at all leads to this same problem. I have a live disk, but I don't know ow to fix this problem with it. I know reinstalling would be a solution but is there any way to fix this without doing that? Please help. Thanks!]

This is the image of what loads on my screen when I try I try to boot up ubuntu. I don't know how to fix this error. The Kernel is tainted, and I'm not able to fix anything at the moment because accessing any mode at all leads to this same problem. I have a live disk, but I don't know ow to fix this problem with it. I know reinstalling would be a solution but is there any way to fix this without doing that? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I tried booting from an older kernel and the same error came up except that kernel isn't tainted.

Comment: Are you sure that GRUB is looking for the correct storage device to boot from?

Comment: Yeah, earlier I removed the live usb and tried booting all of the kernels but the same error shows up and the older one isn't tainted

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/910218/sbin-init-no-such-file-or-directory-not-able-to-boot-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix good research, some similarities to this q, but the dup doesn't provide any solution. I suspect a blown file system, and/or their old BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lets first check your file system for errors.**

For 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

---

**Looks like you've got an old BIOS.**

Go to https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z97-PC-Mate.html and get the newer version, install it (if you can) and see if that solves the problem.

See https://us.msi.com/files/pdf/How_to_flash_the_BIOS.doc for BIOS update instructions.

**Update #1:**

A Ubuntu reinstall was required to fix the problem.

Comment: So I went into the grub menu here and selected the Recovery Mode from an older kernel (image here: https://ibb.co/djQj8JH). After I press enter, this screen immediately appears as it boots, there are no other options (image here: https://ibb.co/4JSGQpw)

Comment: @Rishika try the 2nd fsck method. Report back.

Comment: I've used the second method and the same error came up except now it says '/bin/sh: 0: Can't open noquiet' instead of '/bin/sh: 0: Can't open recovery'.

Comment: @Rishika You probably have a blown file system, and will probably require a Ubuntu reinstall, but try the BIOS update first. I've updated my answer with instructions on how to perform the update.

Comment: @Rishika status please...

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I reinstalled fresh from a live  because nothing seemed to work. The kernel issue fixed itself after that, and BIOS wasn't an issue either. I updated the nvidia driver. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo Please don't cross-post, or add your problem to another user's thread.

Comment: Sry , just desperate to get my old data back.