# Cant boot my Ubuntu 20.04 Installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, system

I don't want to loose all my files, as I have already tried fixing it with the live USB but fail to repair my installation. In get the following text while loading Ubuntu 20.04:

```
mount: mounting/dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting/dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
run-init: can't execute '/sbin/init': No such fileor directory
run-init: can't execute '/etc/init': No such file or directory
run-init: can't execute '/bin/init': No such file or directory
run-init: can't execute '/bin/sh': No such file or directory
run-init: can't execute '': No such file or directory
No init found. Try passing init=bootarg.
```

I already used the Boot repair Utilitiy; I receive the following info:

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/mmcblk0.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

mmcblk0p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

mmcblk0p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32776 of /dev/sda1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Linux on mmcblk0p2

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, focal, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot enabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0014
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,0012,0013,0014,0015,0016
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,1202260b-16ac-4f21-a9bd-0e7a3112609a,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,1202260b-16ac-4f21-a9bd-0e7a3112609a,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(86488440-41bb-42c7-93ac-450fbf7766bf)
Boot0012* ATA HDD:  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f600)
Boot0013* eMMC Card: SanDisk iNAND 128GB    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x0)/eMMC(0)/Ctrl(0x0)c.J8.p[H...S....
Boot0014* USB HDD: Generic Flash Disk   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x15,0x0)/USB(0,0)3.!..3.G..A.....
Boot0015* USB CD:   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot0016* USB LAN:  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,e854bca4cae7704ca322b00da0376322)

bed45d1c9554cea09924d3814cb7c446   mmcblk0p1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   mmcblk0p1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
98bea152fadd26c4e9136916f6cc32a8   mmcblk0p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   mmcblk0p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   mmcblk0p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   mmcblk0p1/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

mmcblk0 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    mmc-disk, has-os,   1 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

mmcblk0p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
mmcblk0p2   : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ng, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

mmcblk0p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
mmcblk0p2   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

mmcblk0p1   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, mmcblk0
mmcblk0p2   : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, mmcblk0

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk mmcblk0: 116.49 GiB, 125069950976 bytes, 244277248 sectors
Disk identifier: A0500CFF-8183-4109-BC05-AB937C067B0A
            Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
mmcblk0p1    2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
mmcblk0p2 1050624 244275199 243224576  116G Linux filesystem
Disk sda: 7.51 GiB, 8053063680 bytes, 15728640 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x42a1f8f1
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *     2048 15728639 15726592  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:8053MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Generic Flash Disk:;
1:1049kB:8053MB:8052MB:fat32::boot, lba;
mmcblk0:125GB:sd/mmc:512:512:gpt:MMC DF4128:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:125GB:125GB:ext4::;
mmcblk0boot0:4194kB:sd/mmc:512:512:unknown:Generic SD/MMC Storage Card:;
mmcblk0boot1:4194kB:sd/mmc:512:512:unknown:Generic SD/MMC Storage Card:;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME         FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                         
└─sda1       vfat     E61D-C222                            42a1f8f1-01                          UBUNTU 20_0 
mmcblk0                                                                                                     
├─mmcblk0p1  vfat     6B9A-9D40                            1202260b-16ac-4f21-a9bd-0e7a3112609a             EFI System Partition
└─mmcblk0p2  ext4     cd3c01aa-8414-42d6-9a10-d85128d31004 85d1fb8d-4af0-4b54-b293-193597e2e0ed             
mmcblk0boot0                                                                                                
mmcblk0boot1                                                                                                

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

           Avail Use% Mounted on
mmcblk0p1 503.2M   2% /mnt/boot-sav/mmcblk0p1
mmcblk0p2 100.8G   6% /mnt/boot-sav/mmcblk0p2
sda1          5G  34% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

mmcblk0p1 rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
mmcblk0p2 rw,relatime
sda1      ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

=================== mmcblk0p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid cd3c01aa-8414-42d6-9a10-d85128d31004 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== mmcblk0p2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   cd3c01aa-8414-42d6-9a10-d85128d31004
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-29-generic   cd3c01aa-8414-42d6-9a10-d85128d31004
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-28-generic   cd3c01aa-8414-42d6-9a10-d85128d31004
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

================= mmcblk0p2: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  81.064418793 = 87.042256896   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             2
   6.972770691 = 7.486955520    boot/vmlinuz                                   1
  41.379020691 = 44.430385152   boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-28-generic                  1
   6.972770691 = 7.486955520    boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-29-generic                  1
  41.379020691 = 44.430385152   boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
  41.639976501 = 44.710584320   boot/initrd.img                                4
  41.632968903 = 44.703059968   boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic               2
  41.639976501 = 44.710584320   boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-29-generic               4
  41.632968903 = 44.703059968   boot/initrd.img.old                            2

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings

========================= sda1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1


Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here is [another AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910218/sbin-init-no-such-file-or-directory-not-able-to-boot-ubuntu-desktop) question about the same error; note, if you boot into an environment, you *can* backup your data before proceeding.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and your time... I will try it :)