# Kernel Paniced after trying to compiling & installing an app and then deleting its folder

Tags: boot, compiling, make, support, checkinstall

Hi today i downloaded the angband game and decided to compile it myself so i extracted the files and ran these commands on my terminal

```
./autogen.sh 
./configure --with-no-install
sudo checkinstall
```

After that checkinstall failed to make a .deb package i deleted the whole folder containing all of the stuff.( I know i shouldn't have messed with things i don't know) And my PC froze then i restarted my PC and this screen appeared . even when i chose linux-recovery from the boot menu *this_screen appeared again. My PC literally will not boot. :(
Can someone help me how to fix it or even teach me how to backup my files so i can install Ubuntu again ??

I was using Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa on my PC (desktop)
BTW *this_screen :

[image]

Comment: You refer to "this screen", but no picture (or URL pointing to a picture) was provided, were we supposed to see something?  We also don't know what OS & release you were using, nor *flavor* (desktop? server? appliance? device? etc)

Comment: @guiverc sorry here is the pic https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/lv4y7z/help_i_messed_up_my_pc/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Comment: see this https://askubuntu.com/q/17647/283843 and this https://askubuntu.com/q/910218/283843

Comment: How and what did you delete? Did you do something like `sudo rm -rf /*`?

Comment: No I deleted it with the delete button in my keyboard

Comment: Did you delete the `/sbin` folder (which is actually a symlink)?