# Error message here end Kernel Panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00

Tags: 20.04, kernel, initramfs, fsck, init

My OS crashed while I was using normally the navigator and a text editor, so I've decided to force the shutdown manually, when the screen turned on and is loading the OS it appeared that busybox screen where I am supposed to type something in initramfs, so I have typed:

`<initramfs> fsck /dev/sda2/`

And I typed yes in all questions during the process,

I am facing this screen each time when I turn on the PC:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vicds.jpg)

How could I proceed to deal and fix it?? I have searched in whole net any answer that could help me out but it looks like that there are no solutions for it. My Ubuntu version is the Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa

I have tried to run these commands below from this post [/sbin/init : no such file or directory | Not able to boot ubuntu desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910218/sbin-init-no-such-file-or-directory-not-able-to-boot-ubuntu-desktop) suggested by TopHat about update my kernel but when I did `sudo mount -a` I faced: `sudo: error while shared libraries: libselinux.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory`

Comment: Boot from live media and see if that gives any errors. If it does not re install the entire OS.