# I messed up with bash and system is kernel panicking

Tags: 16.04, server, kernel

[image: Kernel Panic]

I am in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server and I messed with Bash and now I am here at kernel panic. Please help if there is any possible workaround for restoring Bash.

Comment: What exactly did you do to cause this ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen i unistalled bash and tried to re-install

Comment: That is a difficult problem to solve. You will need to investigate from a live usb and chroot into your ubuntu root partition and investigate. You can try to first boot an older kernel. Once you chroot you can see if bash is working. You can then perhaps try to debug why /sbin/init . See https://askubuntu.com/questions/17647/target-filesystem-doesnt-have-requested-sbin-init . You also may have removed more than bash so perhaps reinstall ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot . If none of that really makes sense, perhaps reinstall and restore from backup. One final piece of advice, in general removing and reinstalling rarely fixes problems and please ask first if you have an issue.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen It was an emergency I had the backup so formatted and set that server again. Anyways your help is much appreciated